# meteor globalization: deployment to different languages

Tags: javascript, meteor, globalization

I want to deploy 2 meteor sites with different languages. The idea is not that the user have the possibility to change the languages, but that the sites are in different languages. What would be my options?

I don't really need to save it on the database, so I'm looking for something faster and lighter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i18n support can easly be added though the atmosphere package manager:
i can suggest the package here: https://atmospherejs.com/package/i18n

if that doesnt suit your needs, there are others:
https://atmospherejs.com/?q=i18n

to install atmosphere packages you need meteorite:
https://atmospherejs.com/docs/installing

Comment: That'll do! Thanks Alexander!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easiest solution at the time being is to use the [just-i18n package](https://github.com/subhog/meteor-just-i18n/).

If you need help, [I wrote a little gist on how to use it properly](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/23d11de87fe80d7724cd). I also added a feature to set the default language for a user according to his browser locale.

Comment: Thanks Julien, I had no time to implement it yet, but the explanation looks better than the just-i18n one. Will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may install the globalization plugin of cordova by typing the following line:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-globalization@1.0.2
```

I have found a blog post on meteor globalization but for the deployment to different currencies: http://blog.sanuker.com/?p=554
Hope it helps!